# Can the Death Cleric's Channel Divinity stack with the Paladin's Smite?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, paladin

The paladin class states that

> at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target.

The Death Cleric Domain states that at 2nd level

> when the cleric hits a creature with a melee attack, the cleric can use channel divinity to deal extra necrotic damage

Can a death cleric/ paladin multiclass expend spell slots to deal extra damage with smite *and* stack channel divinity to deal extra damage on the same attack?

Answer (score 13):

Certainly.

There are a number of ways to boost damage (or other stats). In general, if abilities don't have the same name, then they stack. Since they don't share a name, they stack. You can also add on other abilities. So, if your Cleric/Paladin picked up some levels in Rogue, you could get a Divinely Channeled Smite Sneak Attack with no problems.

If you're concerned this might be over powered, it's not. The reason is that Smite and Channel Divinity are limited resources; you can only do that combo once or twice per battle.

Comment: Let's throw in some Hunter levels for *Hunter's Mark* and  *Colossus Slayer* while we are at it too!  Now things are getting out of hand.... >.>

Comment: @Airtome recent question on disadvantages of muti classing pertains. ;)

Comment: Cleric2/Paladin2/Ranger2... or Wizard6 with Fireball (8d6 in a 20ft sphere) three times a day, plus a dozen other spells.

Comment: Oh, of course! Never said it was *optimal* ....or even practical lol. Just amusing to think of all the stacks.